# C/Cython return value depends partially on frame/function to which the value is being returned

Tags: c, function, debugging, cython

I've been trying to debug this C/Cython program for days now, and I'm getting very close. The [priorityqueue library](https://github.com/vy/libpqueue) I'm using provides `pqueue_insert` and `pqueue_pop`. My Cython pseudo-code looks like this:

```
pick_pop_location = ? // set to 1 or 2
cdef void main():
    node_t current_element, pqueue_t* pq = initialize() // exact implementation doesn't matter
    push_wrapper(pq, &current_element)
    if pick_pop_location == 1:
        popped_after_returning_to_main = (<node_t*>pqueue_pop(pq))[0]
        print(popped_after_returning_to_main)

cdef void push_wrapper(pqueue_t* pq, node_t* current_element):
    node_t new_element = build_new_element(current_element) // exact implementation doesn't matter
    pqueue_insert(pq, &new_element)
    if pick_pop_location == 2:
        popped_immediately = (<node_t*>pqueue_pop(pq))[0]
        print(popped_immediately_inside_push_wrapper)
```

and the `node_t` looks like this:

```
ctypedef struct node_t:
    pqueue_pri_t m
    int row
    int col
```

(Note that I changed `pqueue_pri_t` to be `double` instead of `unsigned long long` in `libpqueue`'s `pqueue.h`, although this shouldn't matter but I'm just doing due diligence here).

**Now comes the interesting part.** If I set `pick_pop_location = 2` it will print

> // popped_immediately_inside_push_wrapper
>
> {'m': -1456.645295, 'row': 244, 'col': 1}

... which is **correct**. But if I set `pick_pop_location = 1` it will print

> // popped_after_returning_to_main
>
> {'m': -1456.645295, 'row': -1739027664, 'col': 32764}

... which is **partially incorrect**: the 'm' value is conserved, but the 'row' and 'col' values have *randomly* changed (they vary every time you run the program).

**How can this happen? What (apparently) goes wrong after exiting the `push_wrapper` frame?**

and

**How can I debug this? I have no experience with values changing between frames.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an amount of guesswork here given an incomplete example:

```
node_t new_element = build_new_element(current_element)
```

`new_element` is allocated on the stack - it only exists while `push_wrapper` is running.

```
pqueue_insert(pq, &new_element)
```

I'd guess this stores the pointer, not a new copy of the element. After `push_wrapper` returns the pointer points to nonsense.

---

In terms of how you debug this: this behavior is pretty typical of dangling pointers: either you're trying to read from a pointer that's no longer valid (like I think is happening here) or you've written to a pointer that's no longer valid. Stack-allocated variables are an obvious source of no-longer-valid pointers.

Comment: Although your description of what happens with `pick_pop_location` is inconsistent with the code you show, so who knows...

Comment: Thanks - the correction makes me more confident of my diagnosis